# how to use variable with as in select

Tags: sql

How to use variable with as in select like below:

```
 SELECT @V_BALANCE_PRIN=E.REC_PRINCIPAL_OS AS BALANCE_PRINCIPAL 
 FROM CR_TERMINATION_DTL E
```

Comment: You need assigning and select in the same query? I think it's not possible.

Comment: ANY ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION PLZ

Comment: If there are not 1 record in table CR_TERMINATION_DTL , you need probbaly use cursors, but they are very low performance.

Answer (score 1):

You do need 2 queries to do this I believe, you can declare and assign the variable at the same time, but not select it.  If you do a select @variable = (query) you don't get the result displayed, you just assign the value.

So I think the best you can do (to use the fewest lines) is:

```
DECLARE @V_BALANCE_PRIN NVARCHAR(10) = (SELECT E.REC_PRINCIPAL_OS FROM CR_TERMINATION_DTL E)
SELECT @V_BALANCE_PRIN AS BALANCE_PRINCIPAL
```

Obviously your data type will have to match, and you will also have to make sure that the subquery only returns a single value as pointed out by Justin, otherwise it will error.

Answer (score 0):

How about two queries:

```
SELECT @V_BALANCE_PRIN=E.REC_PRINCIPAL_OS FROM CR_TERMINATION_DTL E
SELECT @V_BALANCE_PRIN AS BALANCE_PRINCIPAL
```